# Haskell SDL: Can't find mingw32.dll

Tags: haskell, sdl, cabal, mingw32

I finally made it to install [Haskell SDL bindings](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/SDL) on Windows. Using this:

```
> $env:Path += ";C:\SDL;C:\SDL\bin;C:\SDL\include;C:\SDL\lib"
> cabal install SDL --extra-include-dirs="C:\SDL\include" --extra-lib-dirs="C:\SDL\lib"
```

This works, as long as Cygwin is installed for the configure script. However, I wrote a tiny test script:

```
import Graphics.UI.SDL as SDL
import Control.Monad (void)
import Control.Exception (bracket_)

main = bracket_ (SDL.init [InitEverything]) quit $ do
  screen <- setVideoMode 800 600 0 []
  SDL.flip screen
  void $ waitEvent
```

Trying this now gives me this error message:

```
*Main> :main
Loading package SDL-0.6.4 ... <interactive>: mingw32: Cannot find specified module.
can't load .so/.DLL for: mingw32.dll (addDLL: could not load DLL)
```

Now I was looking for that `mingw32.dll` but I couldn't find it on my computer, though I have MinGW32 installed. Does anyone have had any experience here?

Using `SDL-0.6.4`, `GHC 7.4.2` from `Haskell Platform 2012.4.0.0`. Windows 7 64-Bit.

**ADDITION**: I have now also tried it in the way [A Haskell Adventure In Windows](http://www.animal-machine.com/blog/2010/04/a-haskell-adventure-in-windows/) recommends, and that has the very same result.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a 64 vs. 32 bit issue. Try copying that .dll to:

- 64-bit version of Windows: copy to c:\windows\syswow64
- 32-bit version of Windows: copy to c:\windows\system32

[That helped me with FTGL - see here](http://noamlewis.wordpress.com/2012/12/16/cabal-install-ftgl-on-windows-and-getting-exes-that-use-it-to-work/)

Comment: But there is no `mingw32.dll` anywhere on my system. Googling that brought no results as well. I don't think a `mingw32.dll` exists at all.

Comment: @LambdaDusk, do you have mingw, msys or msysgit installed? If yes they may be interfering with your cygwin's build setup

Comment: @LambdaDusk actually now i just noticed that the instructions you're using are based on a mingw build of the sdl dev libs. You should either remove cygwin and install mingw instead, or remove the mingw-based sdl and install a cygwin one, or build it yourself (http://www.libsdl.org/extras/win32/cygwin/README.txt)

Comment: I will have to do the second option since I can't install haskell SDL without cygwin.

Comment: @LambdaDusk, the instructions you linked to indicate *no* cygwin. Am I missing something? Why do you need cygwin?

Comment: Because without cygwin, the `configure` script in the SDL package can't run. Anyway, SDL won't install via cygwin too, because my Windows user name has a space in it...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28242/discussion-between-lambda-dusk-and-sinelaw)

Answer (score 1):

I used MSYS/MinGW to build, and I was having the exact same problem. After fiddling around I found that the flag `-lmingw32` (in the file sdl-config) is being used, and this seems to imply mingw32.dll. I simple remove this flagged, and everything worked.